# How to restore Windows partitionon a new storage and make it bootable from Linux?

Tags: partitioning, mbr, efi

For a few years I created a backup of one partition of my old HDD. I also created a backup of MBR of the HDD. 
The partition list of the HDD was as following:

```
Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             63     80324     80262  39,2M  6 FAT16
/dev/sdb2          81920  25767935  25686016  12,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3  *    25767936 756236685 730468750 348,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The backup partition was the sdb3. It contains a windows 10 OS.
Now I want restore this partition to a new SSD storage and setup a dual boot from existing Ubuntu 18.04. How I should perform?

Answer (score 0):

You can direct restore a raw disk image with `dd` or `cat` or unpack/mount the backup and copy files with `rsync` or whatever kind of backup you have. Then run `update-grub` it will find the new OS and automatically creates a entry in start menu

Comment: provide more information for improved answer

Comment: Meanwhile I fixed the problem restoring partition backup AND the MBR backup to the same HDD. What I learned is, Windows is bitchy regarding restoring a backup to another storage. This I noticed trying boot windows that ends up with error messages "error code: 0xc0000225 ... the boot configuration data for PC is missing or contain error..." and a prompt to use a recovery disk to.

Comment: to avoid this next time include `MergeIDE.reg` before backup (can be done afterward with WinPE too)